# Count total characters in an Array of Strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How would I count the total number of characters in an array of strings in Ruby? Assume I have the following:

```
array = ['peter' , 'romeo' , 'bananas', 'pijamas']
```

I'm trying:

```
array.each do |counting|
   puts counting.count "array[]"
end
```

but, I'm not getting the desired result. It appears I am counting something other than the characters.

I searched for the count property but I haven't had any luck or found a good source of info. Basically, I'd like to get an output of the total of characters inside the array.,

Comment: You initial problems are rooted in the fact you are dealing with an Array object which contains a collection of String objects. Unlike C and a number of other languages, a String is *not* an Array of characters.

Comment: If you will be writing a significant amount of Ruby, I highly recommend picking up *The Ruby Way* (http://goo.gl/8qa79) and *Eloquent Ruby* (http://goo.gl/oa8lc). These are books to be read in bites, not studied. Read and re-read them. And then find some Ruby code to read and savor.

Answer (score 9):

Wing's Answer will work, but just for fun here are a few alternatives

```
['peter' , 'romeo' , 'bananas', 'pijamas'].inject(0) {|c, w| c += w.length }
```

or

```
['peter' , 'romeo' , 'bananas', 'pijamas'].join.length
```

The real issue is that `string.count` is not the method you're looking for. ([Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-count))

Comment: These examples are much more idiomatic Ruby than Wing Leong's example.

Comment: Actually, you could use string.count with a different approach. The fundamental issue is in understanding that what you have here is an Array object and a collection of String objects. It *isn't* an array of characters ala C.

Answer (score 5):

Or...

```
a.map(&:size).reduce(:+) # from Andrew: reduce(0, :+)
```

Comment: The `reduce` doesn’t even need the `&` and can be simply: `reduce(:+)`. Also note that if the array is empty, this will give `nil`; change it to `reduce(0, :+)` to have it return `0` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```rb
['peter' , 'romeo' , 'bananas', 'pijamas'].join('').size
```

Answer (score 2):

An interesting result :)

```
>> array = []
>> 1_000_000.times { array << 'foo' }
>> Benchmark.bmbm do |x|                                          
>>   x.report('mapreduce') { array.map(&:size).reduce(:+) }       
>>   x.report('mapsum') { array.map(&:size).sum }                 
>>   x.report('inject') { array.inject(0) { |c, w| c += w.length } }   
>>   x.report('joinsize') { array.join('').size }                   
>>   x.report('joinsize2') { array.join.size }                      
>> end

Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
mapreduce   0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.222946)
mapsum      0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.210070)
inject      0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.158709)
joinsize    0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.116889)
joinsize2   0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.071718)
------------------------------------ total: 0.770000sec

                user     system      total        real
mapreduce   0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.228385)
mapsum      0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.207359)
inject      0.160000   0.000000   0.160000 (  0.156711)
joinsize    0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.116652)
joinsize2   0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.069612)
```

so it looks like `array.join.size` has the lowest runtime

Comment: i just made a curious check to see which runs fastest given a big set of data and presented it here. you're right that this actually falls under premature optmization, but if it can be optimized in less than 5 minutes, then i say do it. (i changed the wording for you.)

Comment: I will agree that often clever functional solutions in Ruby create too many objects and can in fact be way too slow. (That's the problem with mapreduce.) At $dayjob, we once reduced some runtime from days to minutes by replacing a single `.merge` with `.merge!`.

Comment: There is no need of arguing in this particular case. joinsize2 is the best both in efficiency and reliability/readability/maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['peter' , 'romeo' , 'bananas', 'pijamas']

count = 0
a.each {|s| count += s.length}
puts count
```

Comment: If you accumulate values in a each loop, you could try to do it with a `map`/`inject`/`each_with_object` loop.

Comment: @oldergod `each_with_object` likely wouldn’t work here since `Numeric`s are immutable.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I was speaking in a general manner. He should pick the one that fits its case the most.

Comment: Ha, I am new to Ruby, so may be this is not best for Ruby =)